# how to create domain specific domain admin

Tags: domain-access

I am using domain access module to create different sites using subdomain. I want to create domain specifc admins so that they can view only listing of their own domain and want to able to install modules,themes etc all action on their specific domains.

Only Super admin should able to see all listings without any restricitons .

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Modules can be installed/uninstalled for the whole site not just for an user or URL.

Comment: Ok. fine. Is it possible to create subdoamin site specifc admin so they can view only their user list ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Access Domain module.

What you have to do is:

A- Create a user role. Example: [domain A admin]

B- Give that [domain A admin] user permission to access the admin menu system as well as other permission you want.

C- Go to domain module settings - admin/structure/domain/roles Now restrict the [domain A admin] to the domain you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Domain Admin](https://drupal.org/project/domain_admin) module

> The granularity of the assignable permissions can be determined by the
>   site admin - some site admins will just want to delegate all power
>   over a domain to their domain managers and don't want their
>   permissions page cluttered up with lots of checkboxes, whereas others
>   may want to delegate some aspects of domain administration and
>   withhold others. Hence there is a setting that allows the admin to
>   choose between having one "administer own domains" permission or a lot
>   of smaller permissions.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Can you please give a example how to use it.